# What is the name of this plant with leaves having two different shades of green?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I am trying to find the name of this plant. I am attaching the relevant images. Thank you for your help.
[image]
[image]

Location: Hyderabad, India

Comment: They just look like juvenile leaves...

Comment: I have been looking at this plant for a while now and the colour has been consistent with leaves. It might be possible that they are juvenile leaves and are taking their time. Any ideas with what the name of this plant is?

Comment: Do you have any images of the flowers of this plant, or if not, would you know how the flowers might look like? This will help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Help from Taimur in above answer, I was able to deduce that the picture that I posted belongs to Ficus Benjamina.

Answer (score 5):

So after searching a bit, I think this plant is of the genus *Ficus*:

[image: https://nurserylive.com/buy-hedges-boundary-fence-plants-online-in-india/ficus-panda-plant-plants-in-india]

I am still unaware of the species but the nearest I could find was *Ficus retusa*. I hope I have been of help.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Taimur for your help. You have narrowed my search area.

Comment: Hi, I found that the pictures that I attached might belong to Ficus Benjamina. It is grown as ornamental plant where I live.

Comment: @vamsidharmuthireddy great, if you are certain of it, you can answer your own question then. I am glad I was of help.